# FFMPEG Encoding a video from a Readable stream

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, ffmpeg

I'm facing an issue with the `seeked` event in Chrome. The issue seems to be due to how the video being seeked is encoded.

The problem seems to occur most frequently when using `ytdl-core` and piping a Readable stream into an FFMPEG child process.

```
let videoStream: Readable = ytdl.downloadFromInfo(info, {
  ...options,
  quality: "highestvideo"
});
```

With `ytdl-core` in order to get the highest quality you must combine the audio and video. So here is how I am doing it.

```
const ytmux = (link, options: any = {}) => {
  const result = new stream.PassThrough({
    highWaterMark: options.highWaterMark || 1024 * 512
  });

  ytdl.getInfo(link, options).then((info: videoInfo) => {
    let audioStream: Readable = ytdl.downloadFromInfo(info, {
      ...options,
      quality: "highestaudio"
    });
    let videoStream: Readable = ytdl.downloadFromInfo(info, {
      ...options,
      quality: "highestvideo"
    });
    // create the ffmpeg process for muxing
    let ffmpegProcess: any = cp.spawn(
      ffmpegPath.path,
      [
        // supress non-crucial messages
        "-loglevel",
        "8",
        "-hide_banner",
        // input audio and video by pipe
        "-i",
        "pipe:3",

        "-i",
        "pipe:4",
        // map audio and video correspondingly

        // no need to change the codec
        // output mp4 and pipe
        "-c:v",
        "libx264",
        "-x264opts",
        "fast_pskip=0:psy=0:deblock=-3,-3",
        "-preset",
        "veryslow",
        "-crf",
        "18",
        "-c",
        "copy",
        "-pix_fmt",
        "yuv420p",
        "-movflags",
        "frag_keyframe+empty_moov",
        "-g",
        "300",
        "-f",
        "mp4",

        "-map",
        "0:v",

        "-map",
        "1:a",

        "pipe:5"
      ],
      {
        // no popup window for Windows users
        windowsHide: true,
        stdio: [
          // silence stdin/out, forward stderr,
          "inherit",
          "inherit",
          "inherit",
          // and pipe audio, video, output
          "pipe",
          "pipe",
          "pipe"
        ]
      }
    );

    audioStream.pipe(ffmpegProcess.stdio[4]);
    videoStream.pipe(ffmpegProcess.stdio[3]);
    ffmpegProcess.stdio[5].pipe(result);
  });
  return result;
};
```

I am playing around with tons of different arguments. The result of this video gets uploaded to a Google Bucket. Then when seeking in Chrome I am getting some issues with certain frames, they are not being `seeked`.

When I pass it through FFMPEG locally and re-encode it, then upload it, I notice there are no issues.

Here is an image comparing the two results when running `ffmpeg -i FILE` (the one on the left works fine and the differences are minor)

[image]

I tried adjusting the arguments in the muxer code and am continuing to try and compare with the re-encoded video. I have no idea why this is happening, something to do with the frames.